# Row color change based on condition

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I have to dynamically change the row color based on condition.

I have tried so far two approaches :

1 -> I wrote a converter and binded the Row in xaml. In converter, I am able to manage my job.

2 -> I wanted to use DataTrigger in xaml directly. Bind my column value and check true/false and display the grid.

I noticed in my project, already people are doing this way.However this approach is not working for me. I guess, my binding is not behaving as it should be.

The only difference I could see between my code and other's code is as below:

They set datacontext to VMModel and has a column defined in the same VMModel class and accessing it Binding like Datacontext.Column.

For me, the colum is not in immediate VMModel.
I have VMModel and that VMModel has ModelIfo Class extending one base class.
My column is in BaseClass.

I tried to bind it a lot, but couldn't get it done.

Please try to suggest. **Open to have any better approach as well.**

Here is my code -:

**XAML file :**

```
    <UserControl.DataContext>
        <vm:VMViewModel/>
    </UserControl.DataContext>
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <conv:BooleanVisibilityConverter x:Key="booleanVisibilityConverter" />
        <Style x:Key="RowStyle" TargetType="dxg:RowControl" >
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Row.PropertyName}" Value="false">
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red"></Setter>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </UserControl.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <dxg:GridControl x:Name="gcMain"  AutoGenerateColumns="None" EnableSmartColumnsGeneration="True" 
        HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0,0,0,36" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" ItemsSource="{Binding Data}" SelectionMode="Row"
        SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}">
            <dxg:GridControl.Columns>

                <dxg:GridColumn FieldName="Name" Header="FirstName" IsSmart="True">
                    <dxg:GridColumn.EditSettings>
                        <dxe:TextEditSettings MaxLength="50"/>
                    </dxg:GridColumn.EditSettings>
                </dxg:GridColumn>

            <dxg:GridControl.View>
                <dxg:TableView x:Name="ResultsTableView" 
                               RowStyle="{StaticResource RowStyle}" AllowEditing="True" AutoWidth="False" AllowPerPixelScrolling="True" ShowTotalSummary="False" AllowGrouping="False" AllowMoveColumnToDropArea="False" IsGroupFooterMenuEnabled="False" IsGroupPanelMenuEnabled="False" IsRowCellMenuEnabled="False" IsTotalSummaryMenuEnabled="False" NewItemRowPosition="Bottom" ShowGroupPanel="False" NavigationStyle="Cell" ShowSearchPanelMode="Always">
                </dxg:TableView>
            </dxg:GridControl.View>

        </dxg:GridControl>

    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

**in c# :**

```
public class ViewModel : BaseUpdatableViewModel<ModelInfo>

public class ModelInfo : BaseModel

public abstract class BaseModel : IModelInfo 
{
 // Here is the column. Which I want to bind it.
}
```

Comment: What's the exact name of the property that you want to bind to?

Comment: IsNew is the property name. So , the idea is if records are loaded from DB , isNew will be false and colour would be green and then on upload new records from file on UI i should display DB + files records . For the files data isNew = true and color would be blue and on save it should persist in DB and grid becomes all green

Comment: There are a lot of details missing in your questions. What is the DataGrid bound to for example? You should read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and update your question accordingly.